# Tree exercise with a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to create a tree with *. I will give a number every time in order to specify the tree's height.
It should look something like this if I give number 4 as height for example:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
```

I would like the tree to appear using console.log

I have done that:

```js
var size = 4;

document.write(
  "<center>" + Array.apply(0, new Array(size)).map(function(_, i) {
    return new Array((i + 1) * 2).join(" * ");
  }).join("<br>") + "</center>"
);
```

but it doesn't work if I use console.log

Comment: you will not be able to show html code in your console. Instead use the following approach. As you are using the console output is in a monospace font. So as you also know how many lines you are printing out you know how many spaces are infront of every *. So just make a loop X times with console.log(y*spaces+z*[stars])

Comment: @relief.melone I will not know how many lines I am going to print. It should work with any given number. I just used 4 as an example.

Comment: don't you like call the function with something like printTree(4). I mean how do you decide wich height the tree should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one like this.

```
function drawTree(height) {
        for ( let i = 0; i < height ; i++ ) {
            let star = '*';
            let space = ' ';

            for ( let j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
                star = star + '**';            
            }

            let gap = space.repeat(height-i-1);
            star = gap + star;
            console.log(star);
        }
    }

    let number = prompt('Give number for tree height');

    drawTree(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to count the spaces on the left per floor.
The deepest one starts at `j=0`. The floor above at `j=1`. And so forth.

Given a height `h`,

- floor h-1->j=0
- floor h-2->j=1
- floor 0->j=h-1

Notice that if you start at floor `0`, you get `j=h-1`, and remove a space at every subsequent floor.

You can thus trivially write

```js
    const h = 4;
    console.log(Array(h).fill(0).map((_,i)=>{
        return ' '.repeat(h-1-i)+'*'.repeat(i*2+1)
    }).join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To clearify my comment. You won't be able to show html in the console. So you need to forget about tags. As when you are printing the tree you should know how big (height) it's going to be. So you know how many spaces will preceed your star.

Number of spaces are given by the height in total - the current "level" from top to bottom - 1

and the number of stars is given by 2 times of the current "level" plus 1

```js
let spaces = " ".repeat(height-i-1);
let stars = "*".repeat(i*2+1);
```

So just use a loop to go through all the levels of the tree from top to bottom and concatinating the spaces and stars

Here's an example on how that works (example also prints out to a textarea for preview purposes as well as in the console)

https://codepen.io/relief_melone/pen/zYYRZmj